# webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad not working

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am trying to check if the web view is loading and if its finish loading and when I try to search on it this is what I have gotten however it seems like it's not working is it because I have done something wrong or they change the code for it? I did set the delegate for the web view so I don't think the issue is with the delegate.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
    print("Webview started Loading")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    print("Webview did finish load")
}
```

Comment: Do you set up in viewDidLoad: yourWebView.delegate = self?

Comment: Could you please provide the code of WebView implementation?

Comment: Work on Info.plist.

Comment: Where is  yourWebView.delegate = self?

Comment: You should edit your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve]. You definitely forgot to set the webview's delegate to `self`, but did you even make your view controller conform to `UIWebViewDelegate`? Btw you should switch to using `WKWebView` as `UIWebView` becomes deprecated in iOS12.

Comment: I press control and drag my web view to my view controller.

Comment: webView.delegate = self must be used in any case

Comment: @DávidPásztor if I change to WKWebView do I still use webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad to check if it's loaded? or do I need to check the method?

Comment: @KUROYUKI `WKWebView` has its own delegate, `WKNavigationDelegate`, whose methods you can check from the  documentation.

Comment: @DávidPásztor noted thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to conform your class to UIWebViewDelegate and delegate managing of webView to your class:

```
class YourClass: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
   @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
   @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")

     //!!!!!!!
     webView.delegate = self
     //!!!!!!!
     let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
     webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
     print("Webview started Loading")
   }

   func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
     print("Webview did finish load")
   }
}
```

Comment: I did tried webView.delegate = self but it give some error

Comment: Don't forgot about this: class YourClass: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate

Comment: I just tried that it worked. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "delegate" in your UIWebView

```
webView.delegate = self
```